# Comparing 2 inputs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello im trying to just compare what is inside of 2 different inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pc').keydown(function() {
    if ($('#ps').val() == $('#pc').val()) {
      alert("it worked ");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="identicalForm" class="form-horizontal" action="userSignup.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="legend">
      <legend class="">Register</legend>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>


      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>

        <div class="controls">
          <input id="ps" name="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-lg" type="password">

          <p class="help-block">Password should be at least 6 characters</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group ">
        <label class="control-label" for="password_confirm">Password (Confirm)</label>

        <div class="controls">
          <input id="pc" name="password_confirm" placeholder="" class="form-control input-lg" type="password">

          <p class="help-block">Please confirm password</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is a semi condensed version of the web page. the inclusion is at the top of the page. if i put the alert outside of the if, it will do a pop up every time i type in that input box. but if i try to compare the two input fields nothing pops up when they both have the same password entered. from what ive seen from other SO post like this, it should work! I am still a novice with js, so i may just be over thinking this entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working with the `keydown` event is because the event is only fired when the key is down. In other words, the event was being fired before the value was updated. You would be comparing `12345` with  `1234` and even though the values would be the same, it wasn't recording the last character that was pressed.

Rather than using the `keydown` event, use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) or `keyup` event:

```
$('#pc').on('input', function() {
  if ($('#ps').val() === $('#pc').val()) {
    console.log("it worked ");
  }
});
```

The `keyup` event is fired when the key is up, which means that the value of the element is actually updated. Similarly, the `input` event will behave the same way since it will be fired when the value changes. In addition, the `input` event will also catch paste events (which may be useful).

Comment: What does `input` event do?

Comment: @PraveenKumar The [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) is fired whenever the value changes.

Comment: So how is this different from `.change` or `.blur` event?

Comment: @PraveenKumar `blur` is fired when `focus` is removed; `input` is fired when the value changes, `change` isn't fired on `<input>` elements until `focus` is removed.. See for yourself - http://jsfiddle.net/m8thu8oL/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `keydown`, which actually executes before you press the key, use either `blur` or `keyup`:

```
$('#pc').on('blur', function() {
  if ($('#ps').val() == $('#pc').val()) {
    console.log("it worked ");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `keyup` event. Also try to use `===` for comparing the values as we know the values are going to be both text type and do not need an explicit conversion before comparing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pc').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#ps').val() === $('#pc').val()) {
                alert("it worked ");
            }
        });
});
```

The `keyup` event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tocicenore/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Comment: Interesting ! Down vote without a comment :) I need to study patterns:)

Comment: There was one for sometime :)

Comment: I saw the downvote as well. I just upvoted both of your answer, it wasn't me.

Comment: I am def sure it wasn't @JoshCrozier Coz I know you! `:P`